# Open .ics files with Windows 10 Calendar app

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-calendar-app

I am trying to add an appointment I have been sent via email to the calendar app.

What happened so far:

Windows 10 opens the attached .ics file with Outlook and proceeds to add it to one of the inactive calendars in there. I don't want to use Outlook (or any inactive calendars which don't sync).

I saved the .ics file on the desktop and tried to "open with" but found that "open with" doesn't give me the option to choose a random app or the calendar app but only Outlook, an assorted list of some applications including Notepad, and the Windows Store.

I tried to set a default for calendar in the Windows 10 "All settings" -> "Default apps" and found that no program is configured for "Calendar". When I try to configure one (the calendar app), it says it cannot find any suitable app on my PC and proceeds not to find a suitable app in the Store.

So I finally gave up and figured I ask someone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the default app `Settings > System > Default apps > Choose default apps by file type (on the bottom)` for each extension, including `.ics`. I could see in the list The Calendar Windows App, and managed to open an `.ics` I had received.

Screenshots with Windows 10 Version 1909:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Windows 10 Calendar does support .ics files now.

I had an attachment on an email which was labelled "not supported calendar message.ics" - I clicked on it anyway - nothing seemed to happen.

So I imported the .ics file anyway as follows:
 I right clicked on the attachment and saved it to disk. 
 I then right clicked on the .ics file and I selected "open with": and then  Windows "Calendar" app from list. 
I opened Windows 10 Calendar and the entry was there. it was actually there twice since the first click worked anyway, just no notification so I did not know it worked

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Windows Calendar app supports .ics import. I think the only way to do it is to import into [calendar.live.com](http://calendar.live.com)

Comment: But in calendar.live.com is also no import button??????????????

Answer (score 1):

calendar.live.com was unable to Import the ICS file emailed to me from Intel "OSG LIVE Webinar".

However, I was able to import into Outlook 2007, then Save a fresh ICS then import to calendar.live.com

Looks like inconsistency in the contents of the ICS may be a major issue hence missing from Windows Callender App.

Or they want you to buy Outlook if you want this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Add Calendar" button that will allow you to import a .ics file from your computer or the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I saved an appointment .ics to my desktop. 
Right clicked on it and chose 'open with', 
chose 'Calendar' and 'always use this app' ....
My Window 10 Calendar apps 'new event' dialog box opened so I could refine the details... eg select 'busy', add details about the appointment not already contianed in the .ics....

Easy As  :D

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 App does not import ICS files. However, Google calendar does. If you add your gmail account to your mail and calendar apps on windows 10 and then sync them, the ics you import into google calendars will show up in the windows 10 calendar app.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.